# NotSupportedException: Unable to create constant value in LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code which returns a not supported exception. Now I am not sure why.

All four subqueries (variables creator, companies, companyUser and locationUsers) return a database object and I only call ToList() after the subqueries.

The error happens at the last line of the code and says:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Data.CRM_UserLocatie'
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

```
            var creator = Db.UserTable.Include(u => u.UserDataTable).SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserPk == userId);
            if (creator == null)
                return null;

            var companies= Db.CompanyTable.Where(w => creator.UserLocation.Any(a => a.LocationTable.CompanyId== w.CompanyId|| a.LocationTable.CompanyTable.ParentId == w.CompanyId)).Select(s => s.CompanyId);

            var companyUsers = (from u in Db.UserLocation
                join l in Db.LocationTable on u.LocationId equals l.LocationId 
                where companies.Contains(l.CompanyId?? 0)
                select u.UserId);         

            var locationUsers = (from l in Db.LocationTable 
                                join ul in Db.UserLocationon l.LocationId equals ul.LocatieId 
                                join u in Db.UserTable on ul.UserId equals u.UserId 
                                where companies.Contains(l.companyId?? 0)
                                select u.UserId);

            var totalUsers = companyUsers.Union(locationUsers );
            var employees = Db.UserTable.Where(u => u.RoleId == participantId && u.Actief && totalUsers.Select(c => c).Contains(u.UserId));
            return employees.ToList().Select(m => new User(m)).ToList();
```

Comment: Usually this happens when you have a collection of data in memory and try to join it with the data in the database. Remember the query runs in the database. Scaler and primitive type data is passed along to the db but not collections of data in memory.   if you are not joining in memory collections with data in DB server. companies.Contains could be an issue? because you haven't actually retrieved companies yet by calling .tolist() on it?  Of course, I know probably less than anybody else about LINQ but this could be something to check

Comment: @ Allen King: Yeah I know, this is why I am only doing ToList() in the end. But now when I do ToList() at the end of the subquery for companyUsers, the error alreay appears there! Still I am only with db objects however :/

Comment: But if you don't do tolist() on companies before using companies.contains, this could be an issue because I think collection companies should have data in memory when running companyusers and  locationusers query. Give it a try. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/

Comment: @Allen King: No this did not work, but if I just run that query:
var companies= Db.CompanyTable.Where(w => creator.UserLocation.Any(a => a.LocationTable.CompanyId== w.CompanyId|| a.LocationTable.CompanyTable.ParentId == w.CompanyId)).Select(s => s.CompanyId).ToList() it already gives an error here, so there seems to be a problem with this query itself

Comment: creator.UserLocation.Any(...) will not work in your companies query because you mix up linq to entity with linq to objects here. You may have a chance when loading creator.UserLocation into a list or array first and then use the collection based contains method which will be translated into SQL IN(...) in the query builder.

Comment: @Patrick: 100% correct, this was causing the error. I did not want to do ToList() earlier though so now I built two dbLists with ints for companies and parentcompanies, which I can use

Answer (score 0):

The error is mainly caused because you mix up linq to entity with linq to objects and therefore try to compare entities with objects in memory.

Linq to entity only accepts the collection based Contains() method or the Enumerable.Contains() extension when the underlying collection consists of primitives which the framework's query builder is able to translate into the constant values of an SQL IN statement such as `WHERE x IN (const_1, const_2, ..., const_n)` at runtime.

You should either find a query which does not need to preload any data or preload the relevant data into lists or arrays of primitives before using the collection based contains() method on them.

It is also possible to run fragments of Linq to objects implicitly and to use the results in a linq to entity query, but to avoid side effects, I would not recommend it.